# When I installed bootstrap and tried to refresh the page I received this error - Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've done some research, but the response often lacks the necessary details to resolve the issue, or the resolution is discovered without explanation. for instance, one individual "manually" examined his css.scss file and discovered the problem. I'm new to programming so I not sure how to replicate the procedure. Anyway here is the error message, and code I've used:  When I installed bootstrap and tried to refresh the page I received this error.

Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home

Showing /Users/vrobles50/code/omrails1/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(/Users/vrobles50/code/omrails1/app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.scss)
(in /Users/vrobles50/code/omrails1/app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.scss)
Extracted source (around line #5):

```
2: 
3:


4: One Month Rails1
5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
6: <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: 
Rails.root: /Users/vrobles50/code/omrails1
```

---

```
Styles.css.scss:

@import 'bootstrap';

@import 'bootstrap-responsive';
************************************************
Gemfile:

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :production do
gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.1.0'
end
************************************************
Application.html.erb:

<!DOCTYPE html>



One Month Rails1
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>


<%=render 'layouts/header' %>

<%= yield %>
<%=render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the `@import 'bootstrap'` in application.sass, like so:

```
// app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass

@import 'bootstrap'
@import 'application/*'
```

Where application should be a directory `app/assets/stylesheets/application/` containing all your sass files.

Also, as you may have already noticed, application.sass replaces the application.css auto generated by rails when creating the project, so make sure you import whatever you had there imported as well.

Comment: Gmat: I'm new to programming so hope you can help lay this out. Do I create it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you ask about the `application.sass` you should just rename the `aaplication.css` file that Rails auto generates and overwrite its content by what I posted. Also, check what @lflores is saying in the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

After placing the bootstrap-sass gem in your gemfile did you run `bundle install` in the terminal?  And then you need to restart your server.  Did you already do those things?

The only other thing that stands out to me right now is your application.html.erb page.  Everything should be wrapped in html tags and your "One Month Rails1" is not inside any tags.  Here's an example application.html.erb page in case you edited yours and may need to fix it: https://gist.github.com/flores8/5573450

Comment: lauralee: thanks again...can always count on you to provide help. I was restarting the server in the wrong terminal bash. It's fixed now!

Comment: I'm so glad it's fixed now Victor!